# How to use Datagrid in Right-to-left (Like Hebrew or Arabic language)?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How to use Datagrid in Right-to-left (Like Hebrew or Arabic language) ?

(WS2008,WinMobile2005,FW3.5)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

The datagrid does not support RTL at all.  If you need RTL, you'll have to custom draw the cells.  You can use the [sample for custom drawing from the CF team](http://blogs.msdn.com/netcfteam/archive/2006/04/25/583542.aspx) as a base.